# three.js dynamic skeletal animation does not take effect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

```
    const animate = () => {

      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      this.controls.update();
      lightHolder.quaternion.copy(this.camera.quaternion);

      //Update Delta - Animations
      const delta = clock.getDelta();
      if (this.mesh && this.mesh.mixer) {
        this.mesh.mixer.update(delta);
      }
      this.rendererElement.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
    animate();
  close(action: string) {
    if (this.mesh.clips) {
      const clip = this.mesh.clips[action];
      if (clip) {
        clip.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce, 2);
        clip.paused = false;
         clip.timeScale = 0.5;
        //clip.clampWhenFinished = true;
        clip.play();
      }
    }
  }
  createAnimationMixer() {
    this.mesh.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.mesh);
    this.mesh.clips = {};
    const boneToRotate = this.mesh.skeleton.bones.filter(bone => {return bone.name == 'topLT'})[0];
    const rotation = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, 0, Math.PI/2)); 
    const duration = 5;
    const rotationAnimation = new THREE.AnimationClip('toggleTop', duration, [
      new THREE.QuaternionKeyframeTrack(boneToRotate.uuid + '.quaternion', [0, duration], [
        boneToRotate.quaternion.clone(),
        rotation，
      ]),
    ]);
    const action = this.mesh.mixer.clipAction(rotationAnimation, this.mesh);
    this.mesh.clips['toggleTop'] = action;
    console.log(this.mesh.clips);
  }
```

This is a skeleton to add a rotation animation. First execute createAnimationMixer and then execute close.
Why does the browser freeze immediately after creating an animation and then executing close()?